# Linux: Changing access point with iwconfig

Tags: iwconfig

I have two access points with the same essid.  When I do "iwlist scan," my laptop can "see" both of the access points.  I want to switch back and forth between access points.  For example, iwconfig shows "access Point: " on interface "wlan0."  I want to switch the access point to address2.  I have tried "iwconfig wlan0 ap " but the access point remains address1.  Is there something else I need to do to make it switch access points?  I am using Wireless-Tools version 30.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried iw

```
sudo iw connect APSSID
```